# Clic normal y largo sobre UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift3

Intento implementando una doble funcionalidad sobre un botón de un navigation bar, para esto tengo implementado este código

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtBuscar: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var btnNuevoItem: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.63, blue:0.67, alpha:0.20)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.63, blue:0.67, alpha:0.20)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
}     

@IBAction func btnNuevoItem_onClick(sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) 
{
    guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
    if touch.tapCount == 1 {
        Mensaje().mensajeSinFuncion(controller: self, texto: "1 click")
    } else if touch.tapCount == 0 {
        Mensaje().mensajeSinFuncion(controller: self, texto: "long click")
    }

}

}
```

El problema es el argumento **forEvent** de metodo btnNuevoItem_onClick pues al quitarlo no me da ninguna error, el error mencionado es este

```
App.ViewController btnNuevoItem_onClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe36990be00
2017-10-19 11:17:05.675036-0500 App[4474:644996] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-       [App.ViewController btnNuevoItem_onClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe36990be00'
```

alguna idea de controlar este error o alguna otra manera de lograrlo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser que desde la *user interface* se llama al método con un solo parámetro, no con dos como está definido en tu caso.

En algún momento (en Objective-C al menos) funcionaba con un `@IBAction` con dos parámetros, pero creo que esto nunca fue documentado de forma oficial por parte de Apple.

Una opción que se me ocurre es crear el `UIBarButtonItem` con una *custom view* y manejar los eventos en esa *view*, tal vez usando un *gesture recognizer*.

De todas formas, no parece ser lo mejor tener un botón con *tap* y *long tap* a la vez en la *navigation bar*... El usuario espera que al hacer *tap* haga alguna acción, descubrir que el *long tap* tiene otro efecto puede ser difícil además de contraproducente.

Según las [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/gestures/):

> ***As a general rule, use standard gestures***. People are familiar with the
>   standard gestures and don’t appreciate being forced to learn different
>   ways to do the same thing.